# Android cutom Toolbar causes ListView to not scroll through all elements when keyboard appears

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-toolbar

I have implemented a toolbar (Top App Bar) of my own to add some extra features. The toolbar works great just like the default one (`ActionBar`) android provides with just the title. However the toolbar hides the status bar and more importantly, when the android keyboard appears my `ListView` does not scroll through all the elements and the one it stops at it is showing half of it.

I would like to have the same functionality of the default `ActionBar` and have my desired items on it.

Main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MessageActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/message_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/messages_view"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:divider="#fff"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/write_your_message"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
            android:text="" />


        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
            android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Menu (Top App Bar):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings_label"
        android:title="@string/title_activity_settings" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/convo_label"
        android:checked="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/convo" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/returnHome"
        android:icon="@drawable/outline_home_24"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />
</menu>
```

Update To question:

The problem was that styles xml had `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>` for my no action bar. So originally I had

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

This change made it work:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add attribute `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to your `activity` tag in  AndroidManifest.xml. It makes softkeyboard push up the views to make all the item accessible.

example:

```xml
<application ...>
  <activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:name=".MainActivity" />
</application>
```

see: [windowSoftInputMode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#wsoft)

Comment: Did that, but the problem still exist.

Comment: Had try your xml in my environment, fill the list with dummy items, but have no issues found and the status bar still there. Should be something else make it broken.

Comment: I believe you are right as I looked on all tutorials and stuff and keep getting this. Now I wonder what might actually be causing this. I am currently looking over everything.

Comment: One question, did you have something like `            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
` within your `<activity/…>` tag? I wonder if it is that causing the problem...let me see if that fix it.

Comment: Hello I fixed the problem. Look at my updated question. I will check you for correct as well as you made me found the problem